# NM broken on new install - not saving oVPN pwd or init mobile PPP

Tags: networking, ubuntu-touch, network-manager, openvpn, ppp

I've (re)installed 15.04 on my X1 Carbon (migrated back from Fedora).

Initially I tried restoring /etc/NetworkManager, but that got me nowhere fast, so I reverted to the stock's backup & manually recreated my connections (so back to detault).

I set up my OpenVPN connections with .ovpn & .p12, popped in passwords & initiated connections OK. 
But at some point (possibly after reboot) the passwords were dropped, but no other settings, and I'm unable to save them. I open the oVPN config, pop in the passwords, save it & open it again & it's gone, meaning that oVPN can't auth properly.

Another issue - coincidentally, not sure if related - the mobile onboard does not work either. I NM I've defined my telco connection & try to connect, but it looks like it fails to get a DHCP lease.
Connection worked *fine* before on previous OS (Fedora), but does not on Ubuntu, for some unapparent reason.

I've already tried removing, purging & reinstalling NM - may need to try so again. Also not sure if it has anything to do with keyring.

In my syslog/journalctl:

```
Apr 29 10:37:37 NetworkManager[955]: <info> Starting VPN service 'openvpn'...
Apr 29 10:37:37 NetworkManager[955]: <info> VPN service 'openvpn' started (org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.openvpn), PID 29713
Apr 29 10:37:37 NetworkManager[955]: <info> VPN service 'openvpn' appeared; activating connections
Apr 29 10:37:37 NetworkManager[955]: <info> VPN plugin state changed: init (1)
Apr 29 10:37:37 NetworkManager[955]: <error> [1430260657.261853] [vpn-manager/nm-vpn-connection.c:1778] get_secrets_cb(): Failed to request VPN secrets #2: (6) No agents were available for this request.
```

Can provide additional logs if required.

Comment: Could you please share the OpenVPN configuration you are trying to import? Omit any secrets or specific hostnames in there. And please also try to run OpenVPN manually on the file (please with `verb 3` in the file). E.g. `sudo openvpn /path/to/my.ovpn` and report back with the full output.

Answer (score 1):

You've likely found a solution by now, but I ran into a similar issue and so I figured for anyone who might find themselves in a similar bind the issue I found related to this bug,

[Launch Pad bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/network-manager-vpnc/+bug/1297849)

The solution being to remove the active GConf file for NetworkManager for the current user, so something like:

```
mv ~/.gconf/apps/nm-applet/%gconf.xml{,.bak} /var/tmp
```

Then log out of the user account and back in again and if this is the bug that you've fallen prey to you should be good to go ( this thankfully worked for me ).

Comment: this is the best answer

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure I understand everything you say.

But *NetworkManager* saves into the **keyring** your **openVPN** password **unless** you tick/check the "*Allow all users to use this connection*" in the VPN configuration in *NetworkManager* applet.

So if you checked that checkbox, the password is saved in /etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/YourOpenVPNConnectionHere

You should check that the password is set on "save" in your openvpn connection in nm applet.

Comment: I suspect the problem may be pointing to the keyring.
  

My current keyring I've been dragging along with me for a while. I was on Ubuntu a few releases ago, decided I'd give Fedora a go for a few months, and decided to try Ubuntu again, so I essentially dragged my /home along with me.
  

My present keyring comes up OK - retaining data I've committed in the past, that I'd like to continue using for obvious reasons - but it may be that the new install is "missing something".
  

I'll backup/rename my current keyring data & start with a fresh copy to see if it remedies the situation.